# Cardinality of a simple set of integer tuples

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, extremal-combinatorics

Let $k, m\in\mathbb{N}$ be two integers with $m\geq k$ (agree that $0\notin\mathbb{N}$). Consider the set

$$A_{m|k}^\neq:=\{(i_1, \ldots, i_k) \in \mathbb{N}^{\times k} \mid  \ 
 i_1,\ldots,i_k \ \text{ pairwise distinct } \ \text{ s.t. } \ \ i_1+\ldots+i_k=m\}$$

of $k$-tuples with pairwise distinct integer entries whose $\ell_1$-norm is $m$.

**Question:** Do you know a formula for the cardinality of $a_{m|k}$ of $A_{m|k}^\neq$ and whether these numbers have a name?

**Remark:** The cardinality of the superset $A_{m|k}:=\{(i_1,\ldots,i_k)\in\mathbb{N}\mid i_1+\ldots + i_k = m\}$ is $\binom{m-1}{k-1}$, and I'm interested in estimates concerning the quotients $q_{m|k}:=\frac{|A_{m|k}^\neq|}{|A_{m|k}|}$ as $m\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: I don't know the answer but it may help in your searching to know that these are called compositions. There is a paper I found, but I can't access it: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01827930

Comment: Thank you, @dbal, I will have a look!

Comment: I think it might be easier to analyze at first the set 
$$B_{m|k}:=\{(i_1,...,i_k)\in \mathbb{N}^k|i_1<i_2<\cdots<i_k, i_1+\cdots +i_k=m\}$$
and then permute by multiplying by $k!$.

Comment: I think this is the same paper that @dbal found, but it's freely available for download.  https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220620848_Compositions_With_m_Distinct_Parts